# B and Y wire connected to Y terminal?

Tags: thermostat

Is it common to have the blue and yellow wire both connected to the Y terminal in the thermostat? I went under the house and looked at the HVAC unit and it looks like blue is connected to C out of the unit (along with purple).  It seems like the blue wire is my C but I want to be confident.
[image][image][image]

Comment: Added photos of the unit. Notice that the tan box with the dial/switch is labeled "C"

Comment: I don't think you're looking at the same blue wire in the furnace.  Look for where the thermostat cable comes in and trace it from there.